# Why can't vendor prefixed selectors be placed on the same line?

Tags: css

I recently realized, when styling HTML5 input placeholder text, that this does not work:

```
:-moz-placeholder, ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color:rgb(150,150,150);
}
```

But this does:

```
:-moz-placeholder {
  color:rgb(150,150,150);
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color:rgb(150,150,150);
}
```

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#Conformance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the `:-vendor-...` selector is not recognised, thus invalid. Rules containing invalid pseudo-selectors are ignored.

Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ue44U/2/
The `#foo` selector should match the element at the example, but since I've added `:a-cow-says-moo` to the selector set, the whole rule is ignored.